# template alias for function with varying number of arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, alias, template-aliases

I have a class template Foo which has several members, one of which is a function bar of type Bar:

```
template<std::size_t N>
class Foo
{
    ...
    Bar<N> bar;
    ...
};
```

I would like `Bar<2>` to be a template alias for a function `double (* )(double, double)` (or possibly `std::function<double(double, double)>`). Similarly, I want `Bar<3>` to be a template alias for a function `double (* )(double, double, double)` (or possibly `std::function<double(double, double, double)>`). This means that `N` should specify the number of double arguments that the function bar takes.

The only way I managed to get anywhere close to this behaviour, is by using the template alias

```
template <std::size_t N>
using Bar = double (* )(std::array<double, N>& eval);
```

In this way, however, I can not call the function `bar` in its natural way `bar(x,y,z)`.

Is it possible to get the behaviour that I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With extra layer, you might do:

```
template <typename T>
struct BarHelper;

template <std::size_t ... Is>
struct BarHelper<std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
private:
    template <std::size_t, typename T>
    using always_t = T;
public:
    using type = double (*) (always_t<Is, double>...);
};

template <std::size_t N>
using Bar = typename BarHelper<std::make_index_sequence<N>>::type;
```

`std::index_sequence` is C++14, but can be implemented in C++11.

Comment: I will have to figure out what `std::index_sequence` does exactly, but this works like a charm! While trying some thins out with this code, I noticed that it also works with lambda expressions (although only without captures). It also does not seem to work with `std::function<double(double, double)>`. Do you know the reason for this, and perhaps a way to get it to work with that as well?

Comment: `std::make_index_sequence<N>` is an alias to `std::index_sequence<0, 1, .., N-1>`. so a way to have a collection of number at compile time to ease *"iteration"*.

Comment: Lambda `[](double)->double` can indeed be converted to `double (*) (double)`, but not capturing lambda or `std::function`. You might change `using type = double (*) (always_t<Is, double>...);` by `using type = std::function<double(always_t<Is, double>...);` if you want to support that.

Answer (score 1):

An other option, without `index_sequence`:

```
template<class T> 
struct add_double_arg;

template<class R,class...Args>
struct add_double_arg<R(Args...)>{
    using type = R(Args...,double);
};

template<int N,template<class> class Transform,class Init>
struct repeat{
    using type = typename Transform<
           typename repeat<N-1,Transform,Init>::type
                  >::type;
};
template<template<class> class Transform,class Init>
struct repeat<0,Transform,Init>{
    using type = Init;
};

template<int N>
using Bar = typename repeat<N,add_double_arg,double()>::type *;
```